# I Uninstalled python 2.7 by mistake and I can't reinstall it in kali linux( latest release)

Tags: python, python-2.7, makefile, python-2.x, ioerror

I uninstalled python 2.7 from kali linux by mistake and whenever i run python i get the following error. Is there a way to solve this

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 521, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 420, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 288, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
```

can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get`?

Comment: apt-get kept throwing the same error

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-2.7
```

You might have to reinstall any extra packages you installed from pip

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `python-apt` module

```
sudo python2.7 -m pip install python-apt
```